# python: pytest for cmd tools

Tags: python, pytest

I created a Python library and a set of Python script around it. An example of this small script could be something like this [rna_ex2x.py](https://github.com/mmagnus/rna-pdb-tools/blob/master/rna_pdb_tools/utils/rna_filter/rna_ec2x.py):

```
./rna_ec2x.py
usage: rna_ec2x.py [-h] [--sep SEP] [--chain CHAIN] [--ec-pairs]
                   [--ss-pairs SS_PAIRS] [--pairs-delta]
                   interaction_fn
rna_ec2x.py: error: too few arguments
```

I want to test these script with pytest. I know how to test my functions with pytest, but I can't find in the documentation what would be the best practice in testing standalone Python script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what would be the *best* practice but I simply call my programs using `subprocess.call()`, check the result code and verify that the program did what it intended to do. See [my tests](https://github.com/phdru/ppu/tree/master/tests) as examples.